# Is MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE dependent on devices ?

Tags: android, camera, cross-platform

I am developing an application that runs smoothly on my Sony Xperia E3 and also on Micromax canvas Tab2 and Xperia Z ultra. However it fails to open the camera for an Image capture, in the case of Micromax A106, and even in this device the camera works fin to record a video. All of the  devices other than the Xperia E3(runs Kit-kat) run Lollipp.

Here is the Intent that I have used:

```
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```

The manifest file has the following permissions:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROL"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

I don't know what the problem is or where it is. PLease tell me if there is any other section that needs to be edited other than the manifest or the intent.Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: "Is MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE dependent on devices ?" -- more accurately, it is dependent upon the camera app that the user chooses to handle the request. That may be a pre-installed camera app. That may be a camera app that the user has downloaded and installed.  `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` frequently works, but it is far from guaranteed to work, because third-party camera apps are outside your control and can have bugs.

Comment: Building on the very true words of CommonsWare, here is how you can isolate the problem of A106. Install a reliable camera app, e.g. [OpenCamera](http://opencamera.sourceforge.net/) and check if it works for you.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @CommonsWare I tried using a different camera app, and yes it worked !!! Thanks!!!

Comment: Thanks @AlexCohn It seems to have worked now!!!